# PrimeFaces ajax resets all p:inputText

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to use PrimeFace ajax for enable/disable the submit button and it works fine except it also resets all my p:inputText .
Here is my code:

```
<p:inputText value="#{loginTo.emailAddress}"
                id="emailAdd"
          tabindex="1"
          required="true"
         maxlength="50"
   requiredMessage="#{appLoginParameter['AppLoginEmailRequiredMsg']}"
  validatorMessage="#appLoginParameter['AppLoginEmailIncorrect']}">

</p:inputText>

<p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="eSignatureCheckBox"
                      value="#{loginTo.userLoginDetailTO.resetEsignFlag}"
                   rendered="true"
                 styleClass="acc-lable-name-check1">
<p:ajax  event="change" update="submitButton"></p:ajax>
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a opening `{` in:

```
validatorMessage="#appLoginParameter['AppLoginEmailIncorrect']}"
```

Should be:

```
validatorMessage="#{appLoginParameter['AppLoginEmailIncorrect']}"
```

Try that and see if that helps.